# How to Implement to compare two documents(.doc) for common occurances?

Tags: r, pyspark, data-analysis

Thanks in advance...

I am fine with Python or R program. My problem is to find common occurrence in 1000's of documents.

Can anybody help in how to approch to the problem and which program to choose.

I am new to Data Analytics field.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at the the following [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to create good posts. Please be more specific about your problem. It is unclear what "find common occurrence in 1000's of documents" means (words, characters, sentecnces, numbers, graphics, zebras? Also, SO is meant to help you troubleshoot a programming problem not recommend tools/programs.

Comment: Thank you for reply... Sure i will improve on my posts... need to find common occurances on words....